# Change displayname of a List with event receiver

Tags: list, event-receivers, event-handlers

I need to change the displayname of a list using "ItemUpdating". The source of the new name is the "Title"-field of the item which fires the event. Is this possible? I tried it with:

```
if ((properties.ListTitle == "Fahrzeuge") || (properties.ListTitle == "Räume"))
            {
                base.ItemUpdating(properties);

                try
                {
                    base.DisableEventFiring();

                    string origCalTitle = properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString();
                    string newCalTitle = properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString();

                    if (origCalTitle != newCalTitle)
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            CultureInfo origCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                            SPList changeList = web.Lists[origCalTitle];

                            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo((int)web.Language);

                            changeList.Title = newCalTitle;
                            changeList.Update();

                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    base.EnableEventFiring();
                }
            }
```

I also tried it on some other way, like ItemUpdating and Afterproperties but nothing happens. Unfortunately I am not a pro in programming Event Receiver und also Google doesn´t help me out, so I need help.

Thanks for all effort!

Answer (score 1):

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            if ((properties.ListTitle == "Fahrzeuge") || (properties.ListTitle == "Räume"))
            {

            string currentTitle = properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString();
            string newTitle = properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString();

            if (currentTitle != newTitle)
            {
                properties.AfterProperties["Title"] = calTitle;
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the code in the ItemUpdated.

I have gone through your code, sorry i missed that your elevating user lol, i can see that your using the properties object. As your using that its only read only. You have two things you can do here:

1) create the spsite and spweb object to update the list

or

2) use the itembefore and after to change the title

[ItemUpdating not saving field values](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41649/itemupdating-not-saving-field-values)

```
    string calTitle = properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString();

    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
    using (SpWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
       web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

       SPList changelist = web.Lists[calTitle];

       changelist.Title = calTitle;
       changelist.Description = calTitle;

       changelist.Update();
       web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
```

or

if i got this right the properties should look somthing like this:

```
    public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            if ((properties.ListTitle == "Fahrzeuge") || (properties.ListTitle == "Räume"))
            {

                string currentTitle = properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString();
                string newTitle = properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString();

                if (currentTitle != newTitle)
                {
                    properties.AfterProperties["Title"] = calTitle;
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994981/how-to-update-one-list-from-another-using-itemupdated-event-receiver-in-sharepoi

http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122

Comment: Sorry, but both ways wont work for me :-/

Comment: just ammended my answer by using changelist.SystemUpdate(false);

Comment: I updated my first post with alle my code for ItemUpdated. Isn´t it the same way as you suggest except of cahangelist.SystemUpdate(false)?

Comment: One more thing... I´m doing this for SP2007. Because of this I use base.DisableEventFiring();

Comment: are you getting any errors in eventviewer? does the account have privlages to make changes

Comment: I doesn´t have a direct connection to SharePoint so that I can´t use the EV. The ER is running with elevated priv, so there you be no problem. But even with a farmadministrator account nothing happens...

Comment: ahh, i think i know the issue! is its a document library or just a list that your trying to update?

Comment: It´s a list (Calendar [Template 106]). Can´t imagine that it´s so hard to Update a displayname of a list using the title of an item :-/

Comment: just ammended my answer

Comment: I think we are speaking about two things...

Comment: I have 2 lists (one Ggeneric list and one calendar) now I change an item in the generic list. The EventReceiver should check whether the title of the listitem I changed seconds before is equal to the listname of the calendar. If this is "false" the list displayname (seen in Quicklaunchbar) should be changed to the new title of the item. Is it possible that I doesn´t get through your code?

Comment: ok i get you ;) , from what i can see from your code is your changing the list item title to the list item title? what is the Ggeneric list name and the calendar list name?

Comment: "Buchung" is the generic list, where the Item is in and the calendar should be in "string calTitle = properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString();" (depends on the items title). From my point of view there should be the ItemTitle in, where the Event was calling from. With "changeList.Title = calTitle;" i don´t want to change the listitem title. "changeList" is a SPList type, which was declared in "SPList changeList = web.Lists[calTitle];". So what I want to do with "changeList.Title = calTitle;" is changing the title (displayname) of the calendar.

Comment: I´ve got what you want to tell me ;-) and updated my code. But also this code didn´t work for me... But there is something happen. Normally I create the calendar list without any description. If I now update my listitem the calendar gets a description (same as the name). Strange isn´t it? Unfortunately the name of the calendar doesn´t change to the new name :-/